# Rails 3 timezone confusions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm confused on how rails 3 timezones are supposed to work.

So I config rails to use Pacific time, and tell active record to store in Pacific time.

```
# application.rb
config.time_zone                      = 'Pacific Time (US & Canada)'
config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Pacific Time (US & Canada)'
```

Now I submit update a model and this comes through in the params:

```
"start_at"=>"2013-07-24 00:00:00"
```

From the console now:

```
>> Sale.last
=> #<Sale id: 24, start_at: "2013-07-24 00:00:00", ...snipped... >

>> Sale.last.start_at
=> Tue, 23 Jul 2013 17:00:00 PDT -07:00

>> Sale.last.start_at.in_time_zone
=> Tue, 23 Jul 2013 17:00:00 PDT -07:00
```

So after trying to force everything to Pacific time, its creating time objects form the database by factoring in the -7 hours of Pacific time.

If I set a time to `2013-07-24 00:00:00` I would expect `Tue, 24 Jul 2013 00:00:00 PDT -07:00` to come back out.  And yet it does not.  I was having similar confusing issues when active record was using UTC to store dates. I had a few tests that would fail only after 5pm when time to date conversions yielded a different date.

How do I tame this? Storing UTC dates in the database seems like a good idea, and I can use `in_time_zone` on time objects for display, but does that means that times in forms must be UTC?

Our application functionality is very tied to server time, and certain thing happen every day as specific times.  So forcing everything to Pacific time seems like it should be fine. But so far I can't seem to make this behave consistently.

How do I make all this not suck?

Comment: i would use UTC for the application timezone and the activerecord default. Use `I18n.localize` method (setup formats in config/locales/en.yml) for display of dates and datetimes; set the current threads timezone based on user settings or a default (whatever makes sense for your app)

Comment: @house9 But even if I do, how do I enter times in a form?  The person entering the time shouldn't have to do a UTC conversion in their head.

Comment: if the current thread is set to the users timezone activerecord should do the right magic and save the offset UTC value in the db, then when you display that value to the user with `I18n` it will display it as the user entered it (converting from UTC to the users timezone) - it gets a bit tricky when you are entering a time for say an event that is taking place in another timezone - in that case the thread needs to be set to the timezone of that location and using I18n displays need to be for the location instead of the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going to be a 1/2 answer, re-iterating from comment thread above with some additional information

I hope to update with more later. There are many gotchas with this stuff

**UPDATE:** finally did a blog post on rails timezones

- http://jessehouse.com/blog/2013/11/15/working-with-timezones-and-ruby-on-rails/
- See also: http://www.elabs.se/blog/36-working-with-time-zones-in-ruby-on-rails

---

i would use UTC for the application timezone and the activerecord default. Use I18n.localize method (setup formats in config/locales/en.yml) for display of dates and datetimes; set the current threads timezone based on user settings or a default (whatever makes sense for your app)

---

if the current thread is set to the users timezone activerecord should do the right magic and save the offset UTC value in the db, then when you display that value to the user with I18n it will display it as the user entered it (converting from UTC to the users timezone) - it gets a bit tricky when you are entering a time for say an event that is taking place in another timezone - in that case the thread needs to be set to the timezone of that location and using I18n displays need to be for the location instead of the user

---

#### setting current users timezone

- see http://railscasts.com/episodes/106-time-zones-revised which uses around filter
- example below uses before_filter
- both assume a time_zone column on the user account

some code

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  # auth the user
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  # Set user's time zone
  before_filter :set_user_time_zone

  # ....

  def set_user_time_zone
    if current_user and current_user.time_zone.present?
      Time.zone = current_user.time_zone
      # else some default?
    end
  end
end
```

Alternatively - set based on browser settings, etc...

see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

specifically: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setup-the-rails-application-for-internationalization

#### display date times

Use `I18n.localize` aka `I18n.l` or just `l` - see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#adding-date-time-formats

#### changing the timezone display for part of a view

User is set to Pacific but showing an event time for an event taking place in Eastern

```
Time.use_zone(event.location.time_zone) do 
  puts event.start_time
end
```

WARNING: I have found the above does not work correctly if event was pulled using `find_by_sql` method, regular active record queries work well

Comment: What's relationship between `config.time_zone =` and `Time.zone =`. Because in my case, I don't really want to change it per request.

Comment: i believe `config.time_zone` sets the default on `Time.zone` - I recommend leaving `config.time_zone` set to UTC and being explicit by setting it to something else in the controller filters

Comment: You are awesome. Thank for all this. I have a much clearer understanding now. For some reasons time zones are just conceptually difficult.

Comment: Cheers, i have been meaning to write a blog post on this stuff - it is very difficult.